# D3 tree layout add 'title' to leaf nodes only

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I can add a `title` to all the nodes in the tree with

```
node.append("svg:title").text(function(d) { return d.name + " " + d.size });
```

How can I add the `title` only to the the leaf nodes?

I tried:

```
node.selectAll('g.leaf.node text').text("title", function(d) { return d.name + " " + d.size });
```

but this didn't work.

example with titles on all nodes

http://jsfiddle.net/chrisloughnane/EcU2c/

Comment: ancient answer but here's an example with links and images I thought I'd share: http://bl.ocks.org/mhauserr/6025921

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check whether the current node has any children and add a title only if it doesn't. The code would be

```
node.append("svg:title").text(function(d) {
    return d.children ? "" : d.name + " " + d.size;
});
```

Note that you could similarly set a `g.leaf.node` class so that you could operate on all the leaves easier if you have several things that are specific to them.